# Проблема с параметрами сортировки

Tags: python, python-3.x, сортировка, список

```py
filename = input('Enter name of file: ')
file = open(filename, 'r')

arr = []

arr1 = []

arr = file.readlines()

for i in arr:
    arr1.append(i.split(','))

#------Sorting--------------

for i in sorted(arr, key=lambda para : (para[1],para[0])):
    print(i)
file.close()
```

Это файл (`abonents`), который должна прочитать программа и отсортировать сначала по 1-му параметру, а потом по 0-му. Она работает, лишь если задать 1 параметр для сортировки, при 2-х не работает нормально, как в моём примере.

0 - Фамилия, 1 - Зарплата, 2 - Улица, 3 - Номер телефона.

```py
Stalin,5000,Oktyabrska,0965652324
Fugaku,6000,Victorian,0965552435
Walker,10000,Row,0669617856
Black,5000,Darknest,0666663366,6666
Cheator,6000,Institutska,0956734524
Kulchitovskij,6000,Pobednaya,0889667324
Korbut,6000,Fevralska,0567452187
Nickolson,5000,Lenina,0578562571
Linkoln,10000,Avenu,0895237123
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы передаете в функцию sorted() не тот массив 
Поменяйте

```python
sorted(arr, key=lambda para : (para[1],para[0]))
```

на

```python
sorted(arr1, key=lambda para : (para[1],para[0]))
```

(кстати, советую `arr1.append(i.split(','))` поменять на `arr1.append(i.strip().split(','))`)

Comment: Огромное спасибо, вы просто спасли меня. И опять все из-за моей невнимательности...

Comment: Раз так, то можете указать мой ответ принятым?)